# How to check if a user already submitted a testimonial before storing to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want my controller to check in the avis table inside the database if the user_id exist already before storing the comments of the user in the avis table to prevent a same user from submitting multiple testimonials on someone's profile. Is there a way to do that using laravel?

I have an avis table which stores the testimonials with id, profile_id, user_id, comment. (The user_id gets the id of the one submitting the form and profile_id gets the id of the user whom is receiving the testimonial)

Here is my controller

```
public function store(AvisCreateRequest $request)
{
    //dd($request->all());
    //$region = $this->regionRepository->store($request->all());



    $avis = new Avis;

    $id = Auth::user()->id;

    /** $duplicates = Avis::search(function ($avis, $rowId) use ($request) {
        return $avis->user_id === $id;
    });

   if ($duplicates->isNotEmpty()) {
        return back()->with('success_message', 'You already submitted an avis');
    } **/

    $avis->comment = $request->comment;
    $avis->profile_id = $request->profile_id;

    $avis->user_id = $id;



    //dd($avis);

    $avis->save();

     return back()->with('success_message', 'Votre Avis a ete envoyez avec succes!');
}
```

Here is my form

```
div id="avisForm">  

  <p class="feedback_message">We are here to make sure you are sastified and your transactions are safe. We do appreciate and will respond quickly to any feedback from you.</p>

    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'avis.store']) !!}

     <input type="hidden" name="profile_id" value="{{ $profiledetail->id }}">
     {!! Form::textarea('comment', null, ['placeholder' => 'Message', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
     {!! Form::submit('Envoyez', ['class' => 'formBtn','style' => 'margin-top:10px']) !!}

   {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$id = \Auth::user()->id;
$profile_id = $request->profile_id;

if (Avis::where('user_id', $id)->where('profile_id', $profile_id)->exists()) {
   return back()->with('success_message', 'You already submitted...');
}
```

Comment: Should I put it in the AvisController?

Comment: Just replace your commented out logic in the example above.

Comment: This will prevent users from writing more than one testimonial - no matter which user they are trying to review.

Comment: It's working but what I was thinking of was just to prevent a user to write more than one testimonial on a single user profile. Not on his entire session!!

Comment: @Namoshek you're right. I updated my response to make sure we exclude profile too.

Comment: @LabelleDoriane I updated my code, please check now.

Comment: Now it looks better. I think you should also add a check that prevents a user to write a testimonial for himself as well. Can be added to the `if` farily easily: `if (Avis::where('user_id', $id)->where('profile_id', $profile_id)->exists() || $id === $profile_id)`.